# how to schedule logstash for csv input file

Tags: logstash, kibana, scheduling

I have a csv file which gets updated every hour.I need to upload it to kibana, I want to schedule logstash so that it gets updated every hour in kibana.I have searched many forums but I found about JDBC input scheduling but not for csv input.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own logstash pipleline configuration. Based on how to read input, where to output the data. Kibana is a visualisation tool. Data is generally ingested in ElasticSearch and then viewed in Kibana dashboard. Pipeline configuration is read by logstash once it srarts up. A sample pipeline config, which reads csv data from a kafka topic, and pushes to ES is given below.

```
input {

  kafka{
    id => "test_id"
    group_id => "test-consumer-group"
    topics => ["test_metrics"]
    bootstrap_servers => "kafka:9092"
    consumer_threads => 1
    codec => line
  }
}
filter {
  csv {
     separator => ","
     columns => ["timestamp","field1", "field2"]
  }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "elasticsearch:9200" ]
        index => "_my_metrics"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link to import data from CSV into Elasticsearch via Logstash and SinceDb.

https://qbox.io/blog/import-csv-elasticsearch-logstash-sincedb

Refer below link for more CSV filter plugin Configurations.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html#plugins-filters-csv-columns

Hope it helps!